# Xcode 13 archive failed: ipatool failed with an exception: #<CmdSpec::NonZeroExitException

Tags: ios, react-native, xcode13, xcode13.2

When using latest React-native version, an error occurs when attempting to archive and export a release build through xcodebuild.

`ipatool failed with an exception: #<CmdSpec::NonZeroExitException: $ Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 /Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/bitcode-build-tool -v -t /Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin --sdk /Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.2.sdk -o /var/folders/v1/wd4zzzf10pzbbgtwf94wnb4h0000gn/T/ipatool20221003-10540-akdneb/thinned-out/arm64/Payload/BookingKoala\ For\ Providers.app/Frameworks/hermes.framework/hermes --generate-dsym /var/folders/v1/wd4zzzf10pzbbgtwf94wnb4h0000gn/T/ipatool20221003-10540-akdneb/thinned-out/arm64/Payload/BookingKoala\ For\ Providers.app/Frameworks/hermes.framework/hermes.dSYM --strip-swift-symbols /var/folders/v1/wd4zzzf10pzbbgtwf94wnb4h0000gn/T/ipatool20221003-10540-akdneb/thinned-in/arm64/Payload/BookingKoala\ For\ Providers.app/Frameworks/hermes.framework/hermes Status: pid 10975 exit 1 Stdout: SDK path: /Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.2.sdk`

**React-native :: 0.70.1**

**npx react-native info**

System:
OS: macOS 11.3
CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4278U CPU @ 2.60GHz
Memory: 384.45 MB / 8.00 GB
Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node: 16.14.2 - /usr/local/bin/node
Yarn: 1.22.19 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
npm: 8.19.1 - /usr/local/bin/npm
Watchman: Not Found
Managers:
CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /usr/local/bin/pod
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms: DriverKit 21.2, iOS 15.2, macOS 12.1, tvOS 15.2, watchOS 8.3
Android SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
Android Studio: 4.0 AI-193.6911.18.40.6626763
Xcode: 13.2.1/13C100 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
Java: Not Found
npmPackages:
@react-native-community/cli: Not Found
react: ^18.2.0 => 18.2.0
react-native: ^0.70.1 => 0.70.1
react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
react-native: Not Found

Updated react-native version

Ensure you have XCode <= 13.2.1

Attempt to archive and export a release build using xcodebuild

Comment: React native apps breaking every release of xcode..

Comment: I am facing same issue, any one know solution let me know